# Puppeter with Firefox works locally on Windows, but doesnt work on docker container

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a project that runs nodejs locally on windows without problem. The firefox is downloaded automatically from npm install puppeteer@latest in the node_modules/puppeteer/.local-firefox

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        product: 'firefox',
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 3544,
            height: 3544,
        },
    });
```

The problem is when I try to do the same on docker.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      product: 'firefox',
      headless: true,
      defaultViewport: {
        width: pageSizePx.width,
        height: pageSizePx.height,
      },
    });
```

And That's the result on docker linux.

[image]

The installation is normal, the firefox is there in the same place. node_modules/puppeteer/.local-firefox

```
Docker File

# base image
FROM node:12.15-alpine

# ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"\
#     PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
########## 
## Update and Install packages
##########
RUN set -x \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" > /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    # add the packages
    ## g++: used to install NodeJS related packages
    ## chromium: used to run Puppeteer
    && apk add --no-cache g++ firefox 

WORKDIR /scripts
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache curl bash
#RUN npm install -g ts

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Show your Dockerfile please

Comment: @DevGuyAhnaf I edited the question with the docker file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use firefox, I used another similar option of puppeter, the library is the playwright.

https://playwright.dev/docs/docker